# Excel VBA defining standard user input field

Tags: excel, vba, input, field, cell

I have 7 columns representing 7 diferent (let's call it) sources of input.

Row 1 of each column has the names of each source.

Row 2 of each column is a sum of all rows from the 4th down. Ex: A2 = SUM(A4:A1048576)

Since I am suposed to make random entries to each column, I want Row 3 of each column to be standard user input field so that any value input on 3rd row of each column is appended to the first empty cell in that column, triggered by some event (keypress, buttonpress, sheetupdate?). That is, the first entry to column "A" in "A3" will be put in "A4", second entry to "A3" should be put in "A5" and so on. Same goes for each column, independently. Also, if possible, I want cells in Row 3 to be cleared in the end.

How do i do this?
Please, answer with full tutorial explanation or a heavily sourced one, because my experience with EXCEL and VBA is close to none.

Comment: Why not just have row 2 formula like: =SUM(A3:A6)

Comment: thats exactly how i have it. Except.. 
row 1 has a String for the name of source.
row 2 has the SUM(A4:A10481576).
row 3 is empty (i want to make this the standard input field so that i dont have to navigate to the end of the column to add every new input).

Comment: (1) What exactly is in row 1 - is it a header value, or does it try to say 'look in row 3 for the input value'? (2) After you enter values into row 3, do you then want to insert a blank row (after row 2) for the next time you want to enter values?

Comment: I added some more detail to the question to better represent my situation

Comment: Sorry.. row 1 is just a name.. i say source because thats what the name represents, but i am going to make all entries myself

Comment: You want a userform. XY problem.

Comment: Your explanation has helped, but I need clarification on what  'concatenating' and 'first empty cell' means. Summing the entire column (including row 3) is easy; inserting a new blank row is easy; but f you want to search down the rows until you find a blank cell, then that can be done, but will take more work.

Comment: Also, what you said about adding a blank row, thats almost what i want, but i thought i could just leave that row out of the sum() and make some code to get w/e value i inputed there to be concatenated to the first empty cell in that column (after row 3), for example, first entry in that column would be put in row 4, second entry would be put in row 5 and so on.

Comment: You can add some VBA code so that when a cell is changed, it can do what you want. BUT unless the user ALWAYS enters 7 columns of numbers at the same time, then you may need to use a 'userform'. The change event will fire for every cell changed, so if a user enters a value in A3 and the VBA moves it to the end and sums, then the user enters another value in A3, the VBA repeats. Now if they move to B3, how do you know where it goes? Last row +1 or above?

Comment: Can't i make this code column-specific? example: value inserted in A3 is appended to A column, value inserted on B3 is appended to B column and so on

Comment: Yes, but are the values entered in each column independent of the other columns, or are they related (i.e. SSN, age, weight, height... all relate to one person). If related, you need a method of insuring they are saved in the same row. If unrelated, then life just got easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else finding this answer, understand that each column is independent of the others so it doesn't matter if the row counts vary by column.

Paste the following code into the Worksheet you plan to use. This will monitor changes ONLY in row 3 (but all columns - you can alter to only monitor the seven columns you want to watch).

When a change is detected in row 3, the column is determined, then the last used ROW is found for that column. The value entered is moved to the first available row, the value entered on row 3 is erased, and the SUM in row 2 is updated to reflect the new sum range.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ColName     As String
Dim lLastRow    As Long     ' Saves Last Row for any column
Dim lColumn     As Long

    ' This will monitor changes made in row 3 only.
    ' - move entered value to end of column
    ' - erase row 3 value entered
    ' - change 'SUM' in row 2 to reflect new row

    On Error GoTo Enable_Events         ' Need this! If error, need to enable events!!
    If Target.Row <> 3 Then Exit Sub    ' Only track row 3 changes
    Application.EnableEvents = False    ' Turn off event tracking because we make changes

    lColumn = Target.column     ' Get column that's being used.

    With ActiveSheet            'Find the last used row in a Column
        lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Target.column).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Cells(lLastRow + 1, Target.column).value = Target.value     ' Move value to end
    Target.value = ""               ' Clear value entered

    ' Get Column name (A, B, C...) then create new SUM
    ColName = Left(Cells(1, lColumn).Address(False, False), 1 - (lColumn > 26))
    Cells(2, lColumn).Formula = "=SUM(" & ColName & "4:" & ColName & lLastRow + 1 & ")"

Enable_Events:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Dude!! This is exactly what I wanted to do.. this is an awesome and very detailed explanation. I honestly did not expect you to write the code for me, this surely made things easier. Thank you so much! I got a question though, is it necessary to create the new sum everytime, if cells in row 2 already have sum(A4:A1048576) for example, or is it just a matter of efficiency?

Comment: Correct. You could just sum to some really large row number. Glad I could help... I learned something myself so it is a good day!